# TextView goes out of screen up and down

Tags: java, android, textview

So I'm creating the custom dialog box which should appear after the required button is pressed. However, when the text is too long, the textView goes out of screen. I tried to find a solution for this, however unsuccessfully. 
I hope you will help me, guys. Thanks. 
Here is the xml code for the dialog box:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_dia"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/bck"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Dialog class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
    public Activity c;
    public Dialog d;
    public Button back;
    private TextView strongHeads;
    private String text = "";

    public CustomDialogClass(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        this.c = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        strongHeads = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_dia);
        //strongHeads.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            strongHeads.setText(text);
        }
        strongHeads.setText(text);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dismiss();
    }

    public void changeText(String txt){
        this.text= txt;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can u share your code?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the overflowing text?

Comment: @Rohit, I edited my post with the code. http://postimg.org/image/ew6lscwer/ here is the screenshot.